# Cross-domain error with Chrome in local dev only. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm getting the cross-domain error on my local machine (although the code works perfectly on our web server). This is a real pain in the butt for development, so what I'm wondering is this - can I adjust a setting in Chrome to not get that error locally anymore?

It's this one:

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///Users/david/login.html from frame with URL file:///Users/david/varReturn.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google has decided that offline file access is cross-domain, regardless. You can try running chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`. I encountered the same problem when reading text files from the same folder using JavaScript.

Comment: The super absurd part: for what I was doing (not what he's doing), you're not allowed to cross-domain offline (which I wasn't, but Google thinks I was), but you're allowed to online. So Google is basically saying "you can't be trusted to manage your own files offline; it could be dangerous!! BUT, we'll let any domain access any other domain's text files online."

Comment: Hi Rhyono, thanks for the reply! How would I use this switch on OSX?

Comment: Without this policy, a web page you saved to disk could upload unrelated files from your disk to any server permitting cross-domain requests.

Comment: @KevinReid It should analyze the difference between cross-domain and not cross-domain, rather than say "cross-domain; can't do it!"

It says no to files in the same folder. If it was more intelligent, it would check that the paths are identical and that it is clearly NOT cross-domain.

Comment: +1, this is much better than the `--disable-web-security` alternative.